# What is the best layout for a survey screen in a website?

Tags: website-design, forms, surveys, questionnaire

I'm designing an onboarding survey for a sale education portal where the learner after signing up takes up a small survey based on which a program is recommended to the learner. This survey is supposed to have 6-10 questions which are all mandatory.

Below are a few options I have been working on for the survey screen.

---

**Option 1** - List

**Show all the questions directly** on the screen one below the other and have a submit button at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

---

**Option 2** - Wizard

**Show one question at a time** and provide a next/prev button to move forward and backward in the survey. The last step will have a submit button.

[image]

---

**Option 3** - List+Wizard

**Show a set of related questions at a time** and provide a next/prev button to move forward and backward in the survey. The last step will have a submit button.

[image]

---

I believe for a larger survey it's always better to follow option 3 for the best user experience but, having only 6-10 questions in the survey has confused me in deciding a solution without compromising the user experience.

Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

**4 pieces of survey design advice**

1. Is your survey super short? Are you expecting most people who take it to be on a mobile device? Then include all questions on one page.
2. Is your survey long (but hopefully not too long)? Spread questions out onto a few pages. But! Don’t show only one question per page—you’ll end up with way too many pages.
3. Does your survey have skip logic, randomization, or question and answer piping? You’ll definitely need more than one page to fit your questions.
4. Does your survey have more than one page? That’s okay. Why? Because you can be assured you’ll capture at least some data.

https://www.surveymonkey.com/curiosity/pros-cons-of-scrolling-and-multiple-pages-in-surveys/